# How to control VBA to only allow 1 instance of application.ontime to run

Tags: vba, excel

I have a time loop using `application.ontime` which copy and paste blocks of cells from one workbook to another workbook every 5 minutes. From time to time it will copy and paste duplicates, making me suspect that there are multiple instances of it running. Is there a way to prevent multiple version of it running at once? Or is there a way to check how many instances of it is running (pending) at a particular time?

What I have so far in my `application.ontime` is the following:

```
Sub timer()

    If Hour(Time) <= 16 Or Hour(Time) >= 18 Then

        Application.OnTime TimeSerial(Hour(Time), Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Minute(Time), 5), 0) + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "dataextract", , True

    End If


End Sub
```

Secondary question: I don't particularly understand how it works in rich detail. Say I start an instance at 6:30pm... it works fine until 9pm and then I start getting duplicates. When I break the VBA, I get three pop up errors instead of one, confirming that there are multiple instances of it running. However I don't understand what could have caused it to duplicate? Could it be that I initiated application.ontime yesterday at 9pm and it restarted itself?

Comment: Not sure how the rest of your is code working but maybe try `Kill` to stop all instances of Excel and reopen the instances you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the scheduled time and cancel the previous schedule before creating the next schedule task.

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Range("NextSchedule"), Procedure:="dataextract", Schedule:=False
On Error GoTo 0

Range("NextSchedule") = TimeSerial(Hour(Now), Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Minute(Time), 5) + 5, 0)

Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Range("NextSchedule"), Procedure:="dataextract", Schedule:=True
```

Comment: Thanks. Switching schedule to false stops the application. Does breaking the code do the same thing?

Comment: No. `Application.OnTime` fires even if you initial code falls out of scope.

Comment: Can you explain what on error goto0 and on error resume next do in the code?

Comment: I get an error when I try to run the code: Method 'range' of object '_global' failed.

Comment: If there was no event scheduled then trying to cancel an event will throw an error. On Error Resume Next allows the code to continue executing.  On Error Goto 0 resets the error handling so that any errors after that point will break the code.

Comment: You need to name a range `NextSchedule` or change `Range("NextSchedule")`  to point to a valid range (e.g. Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")).

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I have posted another question if you have time to take a look..: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254668/how-to-automatically-accept-excel-prompt-using-vba